# nginx 301'ing limit_req rate limited requests instead of error page

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, rate-limiting, 301-redirect

I have a bulk search form on apache servers behind nginx.  I'd like to protect that location so that the second request in a 10 minute period gets 301'd to a "Would you like to use our API" page instead with something like:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
    server {
       location = /search/bulk {
                limit_req zone=one burst=2;
                 ...  SOME CONFIG HERE...
       }
    }
}
```

How would I 301 the end client when they hit my limit_req instead of showing a ngnix error page?  Also, secondarily, I don't want to throttle traffic to the whole http clause.  Can I set up a limit_req_zone without a rate, but have them in my location stanzas?

Thanks,

M.

Comment: You do _not_ want to use 301 for this. See RFC 2616.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `nginx` will return a `503 service temporarily unavailable` error code.

The `limit_req_status` directive exists to change the error code in case they hit the `limit_req` :

```
location = /search/bulk {
          limit_req zone=one burst=2;
          limit_req_status 404;
}
```

The problem is that this directive only allows a range from 400 to 599, so you cannot specify a `301` :

```
[emerg] 3130#0: value must be between 400 and 599 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:72
```

So, if your main issue is to display a custom error message instead of the default `503` one, you could proceed like this :

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
    server {
       location = /search/bulk {
                limit_req zone=one burst=2;
                error_page  503  /503.html;
       }
       location  /503.html {
            internal;
       }
    }
}
```

Then your custom `503.html` file :

```
<html><body>Would you like to use our API ?</body></html>
```

The `rate` argument is mandatory. You have to specify a rate for `limit_req_zone`